# View inside of RecyclerView is returning null

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view

I am trying to set an onClickListener to my CheckBox but my checkBox instance is returning null on the onClickListener giving me a nullPointerException. I have looked at other questions similar to mine and haven't found anything that worked. I'm not too familiar with RecyclerView so I would not be surprised if it has something to do with how I'm initializing the view.

Here is the code in question-

```
Months0Through6.java

public class Months0Through6 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

public Months0Through6() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

CheckBox checkBox;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    //This is returning null
    checkBox = (CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_ID);

    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    MilestonesAdapter adapter = new MilestonesAdapter(new String[]{"Month 0 stuff", "Example Two", "Example Three", "Example Four", "Example Five" , "Example Six" , "Example Seven"});
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                    "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    return rootView;   
}
```

card_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="68dp"> 

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:elevation="14dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_ID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_text"
                android:layout_toRightOf ="@+id/checkBox_ID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_blah"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Another Recyclerview Fragment"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_text"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox_ID"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox_ID">
            </TextView>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkbox is inside card_item layout. But you are inflating fragment_blank and trying to map checkbox to that layout.

You could map checkbox inside view holder and set onclick listener inside onBindViewHolder of adapter class

Answer (score 0):

You should `findViewById` in your `MilestonesAdapter`, `MilestonesAdapter` is responsible for creating items for the `RecyclerView`.

See the [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) from Android Developers site.

Check the stuff about `onBindViewHolder`.